# play framework 2.0 support memcached？

Tags: memcached, playframework-2.0

I read Play Framework 2.0 document,I don't any word about memcached.How can I use memcached in Play Framework 2.0? why disappear in 2.0, in 1.x ,it is so easy!!!

Comment: ["The default implementation of the cache API uses EHCache. You can also provide your own implementation via a plugin."](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaCache) Not ideal, but that's how.

Answer (score 5):

As already pointed out in the comments, the default implementation of the [Cache API](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaCache) uses [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/). If you want to use memcached, you coult write your own Cache implementation, or you could [use this one](https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached).

Comment: I try https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached but get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.mumoshu.play2.memcached.MemcachedPlugin in JAVA project,how can I use it in java

Comment: Sorry, I have not tried the plugin. You could try and nicely ask the plugin's author for advice.