# How to use Memcached with the Scala Play Framework 2.2?

Tags: scala, playframework, memcached, scala-2.10, playframework-2.2

I want to apply memcached on my Scala project, but i don't know how to apply it. My project takes too much time to retrieve the whole set of results from database.

If anyone knows then please tell me the steps to apply it.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999204/play-framework-2-0-support-memcached

Comment: that question is about play framework 2.0 with java, and my question is about framework 2.2 with scala

Comment: does anyone knows the steps of applying memcached in *scala 2.10 with play framework 2.2*

Comment: That doesn't automatically mean it's not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First look at using a local cache: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCache

It uses EHCache by default but you can replace the cache plugin with one that wraps a memcached client, if you think it is necessary.

Example of how to write a cache plugin: https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached

An example memcached client: https://github.com/Atry/memcontinuationed